# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:356:11)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, zeromq

I am developing a basic app with NodeJs and ZeroMQ, however I am currently facing an error, which i cannot seem to rid of. I have read solutions that suggest the program "sends" more than once, however i only have one "send" method. Please see code below...

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var server_port = "3000";

/** app settings **/
var zeromq = require("zeromq");
var socket = zeromq.socket("req");/* sends request */
var protocol = "tcp://";
var ip = "192.000.0.000"; //server
var socket_port = "9998";
var url = protocol + ip + ":" + socket_port;

/*header settings*/
app.use(function (request, response, next) {
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    response.setHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8888');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true); 
    next();
});


app.use(bodyParser());

/** paths **/
app.post('/request', function (request, response) {
    var command = request.body;

    //connect to port
    socket.connect(url, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("connection error : ", error);
            process.exit(0);
        }
    });

    //response to front end
    socket.send(JSON.stringify(command));

    //recieve request
    socket.on('message', function (message) {

        //output message to console
        console.log("Recieved message @ : " + (new Date().toDateString()) + " : " + message.toString());

        //send response 
        response.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(message.toString()));  
    });
});

// test purposes
app.get('/recieve', function (request, response) {
    response.send("{ 'led': 'on' }").end();
});

/** start app **/
app.listen(server_port);

console.log("Server started on port: " + server_port);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here :

```
response.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(message.toString()));  
response.end();
```

`.send()` and `.end()` both reply to the browser and are redundant. Just use one or the other, but not both in a row.

As an aside, you stringify a string, so you really make sure that the front-end doesn't get a nice JSON to work with (that you surely re-parse to JSON afterwards). I don't know why everyone always stringify everything and refuse to work with JSON? Captain?

Comment: Yes I spotted that stringify-ing the string, that is one foolish mistake, cheers for the heads up.

Comment: I discovered/made use of the "response.headersSent" boolean which seemed to have solved the problem. Therefore your answer did not solve my problem directly. However it is right in terms of good practice which I have taken heed.

Comment: ...but why? What's the point of sending the headers twice, which produces an error, and you go around this error by tinkering something with a boolean and forcing Node to consider that the headers were sent one? Why not just... you know, send the headers once in the first place? O_o

Comment: It now only sets and sends the headers only once depending on the "response.headersSent" value. Or probably my answer to your question should be... I am still a noob at Node, hence some concepts I have yet to grasp.

Comment: Well I told you the solution : `response.status(200).send(message);`. The end. Don't stringify, don't double-send headers then tinker to have Node send them only once for some reason. Node is simple, and so should be your code.